# G++: Default Overload For Ambiguous Case

Tags: c++, g++, overloading

Given two functions, like so

```
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, Uint8 f = 0x00);
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, int maxW = -1, int maxH = -1, Uint8 f = 0x00);
```

the overload is obviously ambiguous for cases like GS(float, float, int, int)

Is there any way I can specify a default overload for cases like this? Doesn't have to be compatible with anything but the GNU C++ compiler, as I'm already using several unique conventions.
Ideally, something like

```
inline V2T<Int16> GS(... , Uint8 f = 0x00) __default;
inline V2T<Int16> GS(... , int maxW = -1, int maxH = -1, Uint8 f = 0x00);
```

causing the compiler to automatically resolve in favor of the first (__default) function.

All questions I've seen have been oriented towards newbies encountering this error for the first time, so it's possible this has been answered but buried. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you said,  the definition is obvious ambiguous. what do you mean by a default overload? give GS(float, float, int, int), which function of the two do you want to call?

Comment: Edited to (hopefully) make the question more clear, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, Uint8 f = 0x00);

// this one is not default one
template <class = void>
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, int maxW = -1, int maxH = -1, Uint8 f = 0x00);
```

you can see result [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38cb412f14621483)

Comment: You're a lifesaver mate, it works!
... although I must admit, I'm more than a little curious /why/

Comment: it is something related to function resolution order. compiler choose overload first before try template one.

Comment: The non-template is preferred over a template if all other criteria is equivalent, but I would not do this. The answer by Hurkyl is less flashy but closer to what you ask for and simpler to understand to you and other maintainers

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious fix is

```
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, Uint8 f = 0x00);
inline V2T<Int16> GS(float x, float y, int xOff, int yOff, int maxW, int maxH = -1, Uint8 f = 0x00);
```

since your intention is that `maxW` can't actually be given a default value.

Comment: I considered this, but such a fix would necessitate forty-some uses of this function being rewritten, and I would have to deal with the ambiguity created by Uint8 -> int without explicit casting.

Comment: @Precursor: How would this require the uses to be rewritten? If you wan the default to use the other overload, then removing the default overload from the function that *never* gets picked up as the best candidate with 4 arguments cannot require rewrites

Comment: Not knowing the actual context, my best guesses are that you are trying to do something quite dangerous, and trying to put a band-aid fix on the (rightful!) compiler complaints. Are you *really sure* that what you're trying to do is actually a good idea?